# On click How to filter row in default page, if using Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, filter, repeater

i am using a Repeater control in Master Page and on click i want to filter the row in default page.

how it is possible please suggest me.

**please look at this picture check the link.**

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lf-adg89UEg/UoMznxjG10I/AAAAAAAAA8w/15UzfnLEGL8/w901-h722-no/POST2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="itemRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCreated="itemRepeater_ItemCreated" >
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">
 <asp:Button ID="phImage" runat="server"  OnCommand="Category_Click" CommandName="CategoryClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %> />
 </td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>  
 </asp:Repeater>



protected void Category_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "CategoryClick"){
        //e.CommandArgument -->  Categoryid value

int categoryid=Convert.ToInt32(e.Commandargument)
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Repeater ItemCommand event on master page Repeater control and get category Id on event like this

```
protected void rptcategory_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
 Response.Redirect("default.aspx?cateid=" + ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Text);
}
```

on default page get selected category id from query on page load event string like

```
if (Request.QueryString["cateid"] != "")
{
   //get selected category id on default page and run filter query 
   //Request.QueryString["cateid"];
}
```